# How do I get around administrator priviliges are required for this task when installing real vnc?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, administration, permissions

When I try to install real VNC and enter in the registration code I get administrator privileges are required for this task. How do I get around this? I am the only user on the computer and already tried giving myself all the permissions in Users and Groups. Please Help

Comment: What method (GUI or command line) are you using to install?  Did you try and install **RealVNC** from Software Centre?

Answer (score 1):

You should never use normal `sudo` to start graphical applications as Root. You should use `gksudo` to run such programs.  So after you download the program to your hard drive in your case you would

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo dpkg -i VNC-Viewer-5.0.0-Linux-x64.deb
```

Now to be able to run the application with administrator privileges after its installed you would type

```
gksudo vncviewer
```

To run VNC Viewer, and to run VNC Server with administrator privileges you would type

```
gksudo vncserver-x11
```

Source: [MozillaZine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=2393543&start=90) (which cites [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo))